# How to remove a possibly parenthesized expression from a string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to use RegEx in order to remove version numbers from product names. The names can look like this:

`SampleProduct 2.0`

They can also have parentheses around the version number:

`SampleProduct (2.1)`

Therefore, I tried to define a group for the version number and an alternative for the version with parentheses:

`\s((?<versionNumber>\d+(\.\d+)*)|\(\k<versionNumber>\))\z`

But this yields no matches. Since the pattern is quite small I tried accessing the group with an index:

`\s((\d+(\.\d+)*)|\(\2\))\z`

This didn't work either. By the way, in which order are nested groups indexed? Are they ordered by the occurrence of their open or closing parentheses? Anyways, none of `\1`, `\2` and `\3` yielded a match.

I tried to find out if I misunderstood a feature of Regex. When I experiment with groupings and alternatives seperately, they work as expected. But when I mix these two features, at some point it stops working and I can't spot the problem.
Currently I'm successfully using the expression without the grouping to remove the version:

```
name = name.Substring(0, name.Length - Regex.Match(name, @"\s(\d+(\.\d+)*|\(\d+(\.\d+)*\))\z").Value.Length);
```

But I would like to aviod the pattern duplication.

Comment: In this case, there is another solution ([Balanced Groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html)) that do not require reuse the pattern parts, and would allow the OP to have a cleaner regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid repeating the part of a pattern in a regex and just want to match `2.0` or `(2.0)` BUT not `(2.0` or `2.0)`, you may use a *conditional* regex:

```
(\()?\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?(1)\))
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5C%28%29%3F%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B%29*%28%3F%281%29%5C%29%29&i=SampleProduct%202.0%0D%0ASampleProduct%20%282.1%29%0D%0ASampleProduct%202.0%29%0D%0ASampleProduct%20%282.1).

If there is just one parentheses it won't become part of a match.

**Details**

- `(\()?` - An optional capturing group #1: a `(` char (if there is no `(`, the value of this group is *null* and the later `(?(1)...)` check will fail)
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of `.` and 1+ digits
- `(?(1)\))` - a conditional construct: if Group 1 matched, `)` must be matched, else there is nothing to match (absent `|...)` else condition part means anything can follow the pattern before).